# HTML & Javascript - open before on click open div

Tags: javascript

Can somebody help me with having the .projectCategories display as open before the "filterby" button" is clicked? Here is what I have so far.

```
<div class="filterby">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="filterby_btn" onclick="if($(this).siblings('.projectCategories').css('display') == 'none') $(this).siblings('.projectCategories').slideToggle(500); else $(this).siblings('.projectCategories').slideToggle(500);"><?php echo get_option(DESIGNARE_SHORTNAME."_filter_by"); ?></a>
    <div class="projectCategories"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a style attribute to set it displayed at the start :

```
<div class="projectCategories" style="display:block;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line so that is isn't displayed at the start:

```
<div class="projectCategories" style="display: none;">
```

Or do "display: block" if it is supposed to be displayed at the start.

Also, your 'if' statement isn't really doing anything, since you perform the same action in either case, I would change this line too:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="filterby_btn" onclick="$(this).siblings('.projectCategories').slideToggle(500);"><?php echo get_option(DESIGNARE_SHORTNAME."_filter_by"); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your element `projectCategories` should be displayed by default if it doesn't have any `display:none` css rule.

Anyway, i would recommend you to **stop** using inline css styles and inline javascript code.
You can even avoid using `<a>` tag if you don't need the href attribute, just use a `<button>` instead

I made a small fiddle to show you how it could be accomplished in a clean way :
http://jsfiddle.net/xp94M/1/

Finally, use `id` attributes as much as possible instead of `class` attribute (if the element is unique in page). jQuery is really faster when it looks for an `id` instead of a `class`.